# C# List object being reused when not debugging

Tags: c#, list, loops

I am currently having a problem where I an trying to generate a list of random Tour objects (Travelling Salesman). When I debug through the code, everything works fine, but when I just run the code (or even run over this section of the code) my list is full of all of the same object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < populationSize; i++)
{
    var newTour = new Tour(distanceCalculator);
    newTour.GenerateIndividual();
    this.Tours[i] = newTour;
    newTour = null;
}
```

The `GenerateIndividual` method is a method on the `Tour` object which fills the tour with cities, then randomizes it:

```
public void GenerateIndividual()
{
        Path = new List<Location>(new Location[GenericGraph.NumberOfLocations()]);

        // Loop through all our destination cities and add them to our tour
        for (int cityIndex = 0; cityIndex < GenericGraph.NumberOfLocations(); cityIndex++)
        {
            SetLocation(cityIndex, GenericGraph.LocationList[cityIndex]);
        }

        // Randomly reorder the tour
        Path = Path.Shuffle().ToList();
    }
```

I know the shuffle is working because the Path is always in a random order. The problem is the Tour in the Path is only updated if I debug into the for-loop. For example, if my `populationSize` is 10, and I debug through 5 times, I will have a population with 5 randomized Tours, then the final 5 tours will be the same as the last I debugged over. What is happening here? Is the `newTour` object only being reset when I debug, but when I run C# is using the same object over and over?

Answer (score 1):

"*then the final 5 tours will be the same as the last I debugged over*" seems to point to Shuffle method not working.

My guess is that the `Shuffle` methods calls `new Random()` each time it's invoked and because this code is very short it generates the same results every time. In debug you slow things down, and `Shuffle` seems to be working OK, I don't think it is.

(The curious thing is why the last 5 are the same as the 5th element, and I'm not sure what goes on there).

Comment: Thank you for your help, this led me to the answer. The Random() object was indeed giving the same results every time, and I resolved it by creating a private static Random() in the class.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was indeed in my Shuffle method. As @mayu pointed out, I was using a new Random object each call which was using the same seed, giving me the same random numbers each time. By instead using a `private static Random rando = new Random();` in my class, the issue was resolved. New Shuffle method is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Shuffles the List.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type in the list</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">The list.</param>
    /// <returns>Shuffled list</returns>
    public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        List<T> randomList = new List<T>();


        while (list.Any())
        {
            var randomIndex = rando.Next(0, list.Count());
            randomList.Add(list[randomIndex]); //add it to the new, random list
            list.RemoveAt(randomIndex); //remove to avoid duplicates
        }

        return randomList; //return the new random list
    }
```

Comment: This is a terrible `Shuffle` function - it's destructive on the input list. Just try doing `return list.OrderBy(x => rando.Next()).ToList();` instead.

Comment: I read that OrderBy is less efficient for larger lists, which is a part of this project. Do you think this function is much more efficient than Orderby or worth the destruction of the input list for large collections?

Comment: It's more efficient than your method by a lot. You're causing your list to move half the elements each time you remove an element - so it's doing `n * n / 2` operations. A sort is typically `n * log n*` in complexity. If you have a list with 1,000 elements then your method is 50 times more expensive. If you have 100,000 elements then yours is 3,000 times more expensive.

Comment: You should always do some timings to test. I wrote a quick test app comparing the two methods. For lists around 10,000 the time taken was similar. For lists around 1,000 your method was faster (1.3ms vs 2.3ms - yes, it saved 1ms). For lists of 100,000 in size my method was 10x faster. When I set the list to 1,000,000 elements the `Shuffle` method just kept running and I stopped the test, but the `.OrderBy` method returned a result in about half a second.

Comment: And I got a result. The latest run on 1,000,000 elements took 75,900ms for `Shuffle` versus 643ms for `OrderBy`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt

Comment: @mayu - `OrderBy` performs as well as Fisher-Yates.

Comment: @Enigmativity - as well as = equal which probably is not true. ;) I didn't mean to suggest your code is slower, the link I provided is just another idea.